# Uberjar with dependencies only

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-dataflow, uberjar, shadowjar

I'm using google cloud dataflow to run an apache beam job with a lot of dependencies. Normally, unless I uberjar up the entire project, dataflow will refuse to execute the graph because the dependency list is too long.

Is there a way to only put project dependencies in an uberjar and let the rest of my dataflow remain outside? I figure since the dependencies are fairly static, I could save a lot of time on rejarring and reuploading the entire uberjar when only a couple classes in my project have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific `Jar` task with only the `compile` dependencies for instance

```
task uberJarDependencies(type: Jar) {
    baseName "dependencies"
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Then, `gradle uberJarDependencies` will produce the following jar : `build/libs/dependencies.jar`